# Как получить label выбраного option в datalist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь получить значение ( label ) выбранного вариант с ползука ( range ).

```
<input id="cpu-input" type="range" step="25" list="tickmarks">

<datalist id="tickmarks">
<option value="0" label="a">
<option value="25" label="b">
<option value="50" label="c">
<option value="75" label="d">
<option value="100" label="d">
```

js

```
jQuery(function($){

    var part = $('#cpu-input');

    $(part).focusout(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий пример: https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/PBOdZa?editors=1010
Ниже код переделал под тебя, подправишь.

```
jQuery(function($){

    var part = $('#cpu-input');

    $(part).focusout(function(){
        var list = document.querySelector('#tickmarks')
        var option = Array.from(list.options).find(i => +i.value === part.val())
        console.log(option.label)
    });


});
```